# Can pop_back be used to remove certain values from a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, element

I have simple question. I have a vector:

```
vector<int> SomeVector;
```

which has some elements inside, say:

```
{-1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 8, 255}
```

Is there a way to remove all elements with value -1 from this vector using pop_back? Or if there is any other way that would also be welcomed BUT:

- I may not know the index of the elements with value -1
- I may not know how many -1's there are in the vector

Just a new student here, any help would be great, thanks in advance...

Comment: What about [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for such a task

```
// Remove all elements with value -1 from the vector
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), -1), vec.end());
```

Using just `pop_back` in combination with something like `back()` would treat the vector as a stack and pop off as many `-1` as there are at its end.